# Per person weighted answers

Tags: database-design

Hi I'm new to database design but am trying to make sure I get things right first time so as not to pick up bad habits.
My question is I have a set of people for which I want to record needs mapped to importance.
Needs should be taken from a set to avoid duplicates creeping in. Each person will take a subset of these and grade their importance.
i.e.
needs =[tea, biscuits, toilet facilities, internet access]
People = [Phil, Bryan]

Phil needs tea and biscuits, tea with an importance of 10 biscuits with an importance of 3.

Bryan needs internet access and biscuits with importance of 4 and 7 respectively.

How would you suggest organizing the tables to implement this.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a design like this:

[image: ERD]

Keep you list of people in one table.  Then keep another table with the list of things that various people might need.  Normalizing people and needed things is important for being able to write simple, reliable queries about your data from the perspective of either an individual person or a particular needed thing.

Use a third table to keep track of who needs what, and how badly they need it.

Comment: Is "ID" just shorthand or do you advocate that as the actual column name in those tables?

Comment: +1 but i have some remarks on your naming: 
i would call the entity "thing" and not "needed thing". that a thing is needed is expressed by the relation "need rank". I would express the relation by a verb, so i would name the relation "needs". As far as I know the word "rank" has a special meaning (the possition number in a sorted list of items). In this situation the word "weight" used by the OP seems appropriate to me.

Comment: @ErikE - I used "ID" as a shorthand that would be easily understandable by anyone scanning the answer.  If you look at my answers on dba.se and SO you'll see that I'm staunchly on the "Don't put the table name in key column" side of that particular holy war.  In my databases, I use the name "syskey" for an IDENTITY column used as a surrogate primary key and the pattern [qualifier_]table_key for foreign key names.  This avoids bumping into the word ID which is sometimes reserved and it remains predictable without relying on natural joins, which I dislike.

Comment: @miracle173 - Thanks for the +1.  If I were modelling something for a system I was actually building I might avoid _THING_ as being a bit too vague.  I take your point though, how about NEEDABLE_THING?  I'd buy _weight_ over _rank_.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So you name the "same" column different things in different tables, depending on how it's used. I hate that! I think the "key" thing breaks down too fast and caters to the beginner at the expense of the expert. One DB I worked in had "key" and "frnkey" prefixes everywhere--it was a joke of a database and taught me how awful it is to name things by how they are used rather than what they are.

Comment: @ErikE - I don't name the same thing different in different tables.  I name primary surrogate keys in any table "syskey" - When anyone, beginner or expert sees _syskey_ they know they are looking at a monotonically increasing 32 bit integer primary surrogate key.  That is a lot of information for six letters.  Foreign keys reference the table name like so: customer_key is FK to the CUSTOMER table; order_key is FK to the ORDER table.  This is neither confusing, nor hard to read.  It takes complete advantage of the _domain name integrity_ that is found in the naming of SQL objects.

Comment: As I noted earlier, this is a holy war subject, but for my money primary key vs. foreign key is not a what it is vs. how it's used question.  Each predicate should be understood in the context of its container, not the whole schema.  If CUSTOMER.name and PRODUCT.name are not the same thing, then why must CUSTOMER.syskey and PRODUCT.syskey need different names to differentiate them?  Natural join names break down as soon as you have an involuted relationship or two relationships to one parent, such as in a BOM.  Calling keys "table"_ID is a throwback to COBOL and ISAM.

Comment: Columns that mean different things are okay to call the same thing, as long as that name isn't an ID. Columns that mean the same thing should NOT be called different things, especially when they are an ID. All cats are animals. Not all animals are cats. The idea is not commutative. And FWIW I have started calling the `Name` column the same as the table in most of my tables for the exact reason you mention.

Answer (score 0):

When you design a database  first part is drawing the  ER -diagaram after drawing it, you can decide what is the primary key ,foreign key etc .When drawing a ER diagram  you can easily find what all things are repeating and can use normalization to that. Certain softwares are also available for designing the ER diagram  like mysql workbench etc, i hope this helps